# Why isn't this while loop reitterating?

Tags: python, pygame

For some odd reason(I'm sort of new to python/pygame) this while loop isn't loading the other one. I have it so that there is two players. It starts on player one in a while loop and then once player one is done it turns the second while loop to true and so on so forth. But once the second loop has finished it doesn't turn the first one to true just leaves ends the program.

Loop one:

```
game = True
while game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.event.get()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
            count1 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255),(200, countY - 100), 25, 0)
            game = False
            game2 = True
            print("Test")
            pygame.display.update()
```

Loop two(This should turn the first loop to true when "J" is pushed):

```
while game2:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.event.get()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_j:
            count3 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255),(500, countY - 100), 25, 0)
            game2 = False
            game = True
            print("Test third")
            pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need *another* loop above the two `while game` and `while game2` loops:

```
while True:
    while game:
        #

    while game2:
        #
```

Now when `game2` ends, the outermost `while` loop goes back up to the first `while game` loop.

Ending the game would require you to break out of the `while True` loop; you could use the `break` keyword for that, executed outside either of the `while game` or `while game2` loops.

Comment: Yes, sorry i didn't do it earlier, but there was a time limit before i could do it. once again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`while` loops in Python do not constantly check for their condition to be `True`.

The `game` while loop is executed, as you have said, before the `game2` loop.

```
while game:
    # do stuff

while game2:
    # do stuff
```

When `game2` sets `game` to True, this doesn't mean the `while game` loop will start executing again. The body of a `while` loop and its recursions are only executed once. Python will continue executing the rest of the script and terminate. Without any other control flow, there is no way for the `while game` loop to be executed again.

Another alternative is to turn `game` and `game2` into functions and call them in the other functions when their games are supposed to start.

If execution of `game2` is supposed to end once `game` begins, then something like this would suffice:

```
def game():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            pygame.event.get()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
                count1 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255),(200, countY - 100), 25, 0)
                game2() # Begin player 2 game
                print("Test")
                pygame.display.update()
                return # Stop execution of game()

def game2():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            pygame.event.get()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_j:
                count3 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255),(500, countY - 100), 25, 0)
                game() # Begin player 1 game
                print("Test third")
                pygame.display.update()
                return
```

Comment: This one is good, however Martijn Pieter probably did it in a more pythonic manner.